# Proving that certain set has a maximun

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I have found this exercise in the part of Lebesgue integration of my notes of Functional Analysis:

**Let we consider $1<p<\infty$ and $q$ such that $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$. If $f$ is a measurable function in $\mathbb{R}^n$ verifying  $$\frac{\int_A{|f|}}{\left(    \int_A1\right)^{1/q}}<\infty\;\forall A\text{with non-zero measure},$$ prove that the set of real numbers  $\left \{  \frac{\int_A{|f|}}{\left(\int_A1\right)^{1/q}}:A\text{ has positive measure}\right\}$ has a maximun.**

I am very lost with this exercise, I know that the set admits a supremun because it is bounded, but I don't know why it has a maximun. Can someone give me a hint about this?

Comment: with "medible" do you mean measurable?

Comment: Do you assume $f \in L^p(\mathbb R^n)$?

Comment: @Rodolfo Ferreira de Oliveira Yes, I edit it

Comment: @gerw No, the only hypothesis above $f$ is what appears in the question